# How to get next earliest date from today in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have dates that are past today. I only need the next earliest date from today.

Below code takes the min date where I'm looking for a solution to get next earliest date from today?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    StyleItem.STYLE,
    StyleItem.COLOR,
    StyleItem.SIZE,
    StyleItem.UPC,
    INVENTORY.ITEMNO,
    SUM(QOHQTY) AS QOHQTY,
    dates.Dates,
    ProdOrderDetail.PRODLINEQTY
FROM 
    (SELECT
         ProdOrderDetail.ITEMNO, 
         MIN(DUEDATE) AS Dates
     FROM
         ProdOrderDetail
     GROUP BY
         ProdOrderDetail.ITEMNO) AS dates
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    Inventory ON Inventory.ITEMNO = dates.ITEMNO
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ProdOrderDetail ON ProdOrderDetail.DUEDATE = dates.dates 
                    AND ProdOrderDetail.ITEMNO = dates.ITEMNO
INNER JOIN
    StyleItem ON styleitem.itemno = Inventory.ITEMNO
WHERE
    StyleItem.DIVISION = 'HH' 
    AND StyleItem.MERCHGROUPA = 'NATL' 
    AND StyleItem.MERCHGROUPB <> 'MARKETING'
GROUP BY
    Inventory.ITEMNO,
    dates.dates,
    ProdOrderDetail.PRODLINEQTY,
    StyleItem.STYLE, StyleItem.COLOR, StyleItem.SIZE, StyleItem.UPC
ORDER BY
    styleitem.style, styleitem.color
```

Comment: please tag the dbms being used. like Oracle,SQL Server,Postgres,MySQL ..

Comment: Edit the question with some explanation with desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your RDBMS, it could be one of them:

SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP (1) AvailDate
FROM YourTable
WHERE AvailDate > GETDATE()
ORDER BY AvailDate;

SELECT MIN(AvailDate) AS AvailDate
FROM YourTable
WHERE AvailDate > GETDATE();
```

MySQL

```
SELECT AvailDate
FROM YourTable
WHERE AvailDate > NOW()
ORDER BY AvailDate
LIMIT 1;

SELECT MIN(AvailDate) AS AvailDate
FROM YourTable
WHERE AvailDate > NOW();
```

In both cases you have to filter rows that are greater than the current date and then:

1. Sort by that date and take first element
2. Use `MIN()` in order to find the lowest date greater than current one

Comment: I have dates that are past today. I only need the next earliest date from today.

Comment: Well, put all of that in your question please.\